# Help wanted on distributions of celestial bodies by mass

Tags: universe

I'm looking for help or advice on working out the numbers of bodies in a particular mass range, especially for non-luminous bodies less massive than stars. This is for bodies in interstellar space, such as in the Oort Cloud.

For example, a figure at http://lasp.colorado.edu/outerplanets/images_solsys/big/star_demographic.jpg
shows how for 1 very massive star of 150 solar masses, there are 10 of mass 2-10 sols, 50 of mass 0.5-2 sols, and 200 of mass 0.08-0.50 sols. (0.08 is regarded as the minimum mass for a star, ie a body hot enough to emit its own light).

I want to be able to present a depiction of the number of smaller bodies in a given range (say 0.01-0.1 Earth masses,0.1-1 Earths, 1-10 Earths, 10-100 Earths, etc), if these bodies follow a reasonable distribution pattern -- that is, extrapolate the figure referred to leftwards, into the super-planet/planet/asteroid/space rock range. It would be good if the total mass of all the sub-star stuff could be shown likely to equal about 9 times the mass of the star (luminous) bodies, but that is a possibly a later job.

There may be a parallel with the energy of earthquakes. For one powerful earthquake of magnitude 9-10, there will a larger number of magnitude 8-9, even more for 7-8, and so on. I have a vague memory of being told that the total energy of all earthquakes on Earth for a given period (say 1 year) is roughly equal to twice the energy of the biggest single event recorded in the year. However this memory may be faulty.

Comment: Cold insterstellar object populations in the sub-jovian through super-jovian mass range have been measured by micro-lensing studies.

Answer (score 0):

Number distribution and mass distribution will be very different. For example, there are estimated to be trillions of objects in the Oort cloud, but their total mass is less than $0.1\%$ of the mass of the Solar System (and some estimates put it at *much* less than that). The Sun accounts for around $99.8\%$ of the mass of the Solar System.

According to Wikipedia's article on the [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way), $90\%$ of the mass of our galaxy is dark matter, between $8.5\%$ and $9\%$ of the mass is in stars, and almost all of the rest is interstellar gas. Compared to these three components, the total mass of substellar objects is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for helpful comments. You may have guessed that I am investigating the thesis that 'dark matter' is, in fact, all the interstellar matter classed as in the Oort Cloud. The rider to this is that the Oort Cloud has many quite massive objects within it, right up to just below star size. This thesis may be wrong, but even so I'd appreciate any evidence that it is wrong.